# FSL FIX CLASSIFIER error: error: inv(): matrix appears to be singular

Tags: linux

I am trying to use FIX (https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FIX) to denoise my functional MRI data, but after running the command to train the classifier:

```
/usr/local/fix/fix -t classifier_name -l <path I manually classified>
```

I get these errors:

```
/usr/local/fix/fix -t WP2a_classifier_training -l 
sub-01/ses-w01pol03day01Pre/func/swsub-01_ses-w01pol03day01Pre_task-joystickPre_bold.ica
FIX Training classifier with output training file: ./WP2a_classifier_training and Melodic outputs list: sub-01/ses-w01pol03day01Pre/func/swsub-01_ses-w01pol03day01Pre_task-joystickPre_bold.ica
copy true labels and features into training directory
FIX features not already generated, so creating them now.
FIX Feature extraction for Melodic output directory: sub-01/ses-w01pol03day01Pre/func/swsub-01_ses-w01pol03day01Pre_task-joystickPre_bold.ica
create edge masks
run FAST
registration of standard space masks

error: inv(): matrix appears to be singular

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  inv(): matrix appears to be singular
/usr/local/fix/fix_0c_reg_masks: line 32: 26064 Aborted                 (core dumped) convert_xfm -omat $folders/fix/std2highres.mat -inverse $folders/fix/highres2std.mat
Could not open matrix file sub-01/ses-w01pol03day01Pre/func/swsub-01_ses-w01pol03day01Pre_task-joystickPre_bold.ica/fix/std2highres.mat
Cannot read input-matrix
Could not open matrix file sub-01/ses-w01pol03day01Pre/func/swsub-01_ses-w01pol03day01Pre_task-joystickPre_bold.ica/fix/std2exfunc.mat

error: matrix multiplication: incompatible matrix dimensions: 4x4 and 0x0
```

Any tip would be helpful as I'm quite stuck with this.

EDIT:

I am referring to this program https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/FIX

Thanks.

Comment: FIX doesn't appear to be a standard program. A few Google searches didn't turn anything up for me. Can you point to any documentation on FIX?

Comment: Also, it appears that you have a singular matrix which is causing the core dump. That's what you need to investigate.

Comment: I see that the problem is related to a singular matrix, I just don't understand which is the file I need to check. The file std2highres.mat which the error refers to, is generated by the command I'm running and not by me.